# How to set the div tag visible on post back ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, visibility

I have a textbox that is used for searching. upon clicking the ok button and posting back, the function is called, and gets matching results by using sql query in the aspx.cs file

this information will be displayed in the div tag and set visible. initially div tag will not be visible. after the button posts back, then the div tag will be set visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a panel:

```
<asp:Panel id="results" runat="server" Visible="false">
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

and then:

```
results.Visible = true;
```

or a div:

```
<div id="results" runat="server" Visible="false">
    ...
</div>
```

and then:

```
results.Visible = true;
```